# How to find the cluster name in Hadoop environment?

Tags: hadoop

I am using CDH 5.5 and want to know any command or a way to find the clustername?
I am actually trying to execute the below api call and it throws an error.

```
 curl -u admin:admin 'http://localhost:7180/api/v1/clusters/namenode241'
```

error:

```
{
  "message" : "Cluster 'namenodee241' not found."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is corrent except one last part. In your command you are mentioning the Cluster name `namenode241`. So remove that and execute

`curl -u admin:admin 'http://localhost or hostname:7180/api/v1/clusters'`

[image: CDH cluster name along with version]

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just just access to cloudera manager?, it's usually on port 7180 and it will show you the cluster name just in the home page. In the screenshot below it's "Cluster 1"

[image: Cloudera manager]